# How to display a div on top of another one after click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want a sort of overlay after clicking on a button. This is how it looks before the triangle at the bottom is clicked:

[image]

Then after it is clicked, it should look like this:

[image]

I feel this can be done with jQuery, but I haven't figured it out yet. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a ballpark answer (based on what info has been given...), I would suggest making a absolutely positioned (and sized!) div that appears over the top of the content (don't worry about the show/hide bit just yet...

Once you've got that nailed and where you want it.

then a click event using:

```
$('selector').toggle()
```

will manage the showing and hiding of it.

To start it hidden, for the CSS of the element, give it a display:none; - Jquery will add a `Display:block` on showing the element which will then override the property in the CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

this is quite basic jquery.

```
// address the arrow button with an #id or .class
$('#arrow_button').click(function(){
    $('#overlay').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```js
$('.buttons button').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.tabs .active').hide('drop',function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');      
        $('.tabs div:eq('+$this.index()+')').show('fade').addClass('active');        
    });    
    
});
```

```css
.tabs{
    height:300px;
}
.tab{
    height:250px;
    display:none;
    border:solid blue thick;
    background-color:#88a;
}
.tab.active{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab active">Content1</div>
    <div class="tab">Content2</div>
    <div class="tab">Content3</div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <button>content 1</button>
    <button>content 2</button>
    <button>content 3</button>
</div>
```